# Is it possible to miss messages using long polling with nginx+pushstream module?

Tags: javascript, nginx, push, message-queue

I read thru all documentation, forums and examples I could find but could not find a description on how the [pushstream module](https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module) behaves in the following situation:

I am using nginx+pushstream to deliver status messages at a session queue for users that requested actions that take a little while on the server side.

Using the long polling technique the client is re-connecting every time a message was delivered or the connection timeout is reached.

If there are many messages sent to the subscribed queue at the same time, is it possible that the client could miss a message while he is re-connecting? Or is this situation handled by the pushstream module?

Thanks to everyone taking time to read and answer! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Some random search for a different topic turned up a thread in the Google Groups that answers the question.*

The pushstream module developer states in a response:

> About your goal, you may set If-Modified-Since header when connecting
>   as current time on new user connect. With that it will only receive
>   messages sent after this time.
>
> I'm only afraid you may loose some message using long polling without
>   store messages or with a small
>   push_stream_max_messages_stored_per_channel.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nginxpushstream/4VutBQwx3zM

This means that it is not possible to loose messages if messages are stored (`push_stream_store_messages` is set to on).
The HTTP-Headers `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` will make sure of this.